# bazaar + cruise control

Tags: bazaar, cruisecontrol

The team i work with is using Bazaar as its VCS, i would like to introduce CruiseControl (CC) with PHPUnderControl (PUC) into the mix, but cannot seem to find any documentation or plugin for bazaar and CC. There is a plugin for cc.net, but it has to run on linux yes i know mono but it seems PUC requires CC not cc.net. is there any way for bazaar to intergrate with CC.

Comment: Duplicated in the (later) question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838626/bazaar-cruisecontrol-net

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bootstrapper someone else suggested as a possible solution:

https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/62809

I haven't tested, and YMMV, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Bazaar plugin available for CruiseControl now:

http://blog.fusonic.net/2010/10/bazaar-plugin-for-cruisecontrol/

Answer (score 0):

Custom MSBuild or NAnt script that includes `bzr pull` or `bzr checkout` manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a functioning .NET plugin (with unit tests?) it would probably be straightforward to port to CC Java.

If you're not comfortable with Java you might ask on the CC [developers mailing list](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/developers.html) to see if one them -- like me ;) -- would do the port for you. I'm always happy to help people who are writing plugins and I expect porting a SourceControl plugin would be quick and easy.